# jira api - how to update fields on a jira issue that is closed/published

Tags: jira-rest-api

the following code works fine on a jira issue that is in open. but when this is tried on a closed/published issue i get error. wanted to see if this is even possible to be done? manually on closed/published jira issue, we can update those fields

```
   Client client = Client.create();
   WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://jira.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JIRA_KEY1");
   String data1 =  "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"fields\" : {\r\n" + 
                "        \"customfield_10201\" : \"Value 1\"\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "}";
   String auth = new String(Base64.encode("user" + ":" + "pass"));
        ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Authorization", "Basic " + auth).type("application/json").accept("application/json").put(ClientResponse.class, data1);
```

Error received

```
Http Error : 400{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"customfield_10201":"Field 'customfield_10201' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a restriction that doesn't allow the value of that field to be changed once the issue is marked as complete.

Try opening that completed issue via the web interface and changing the field's value; if you can't do it via the web interface, then you can't do it the REST API.